# pytest dynamically generate test method

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

Hi How can i generate test method dynamically for a list or for number of files.
Say I have file1,file2 and filen with input value in json. Now I need to run the same test for multiple values like below,

```
class Test_File(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_$FILE_NAME(self):
        return_val = validate_data($FILE_NAME)
        assert return_val
```

I am using the following command to run the py.test to generate html and junit report

```
py.test test_rotate.py --tb=long --junit-xml=results.xml --html=results.html -vv
```

At present I am manually defining the methods as below,

```
def test_lease_file(self):
    return_val = validate_data(lease_file)
    assert return_val

def test_string_file(self):
    return_val = validate_data(string_file)
    assert return_val

 def test_data_file(self):
    return_val = validate_data(data_file)
    assert return_val
```

Please let me know how I can specify py test to dynamically generate test_came method while giving reports.

I am expecting exactly which is mentioned in this blog "http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/04/02/dynamically-generating-python-test-cases"

But above blog uses unittest and if I use that I am not able to generate html and junit report

When we use fixtures as below I get error like its requiring 2 parameters,

```
test_case = []
class Memory_utlization(unittest.TestCase):
@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
    fname = "test_order.txt"
    with open(fname) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    file_names = []
    for i in content:
        file_names.append(i.strip())
    data = tuple(file_names)
    test_case.append(data)
    logging.info(test_case) # here test_case=[('dhcp_lease.json'),('dns_rpz.json'),]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_file",test_case)
def test_eval(self,test_file):
    logging.info(test_case)
```

When I execute the above I get the following error,

```
 >               testMethod()
 E               TypeError: test_eval() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html) might help you with this.

Your test class would then look like

```
class Test_File():
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'file', [
            (lease_file,),
            (string_file,),
            (data_file,)
        ]
    )
    def test_file(self, file):
        assert validate_data(file)
```

Comment: If I don't have class it works fine as mentioned in pytest fixtures doc. But when I use setup method and use self  it fails with error TypeError: test_eval() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Could you add that as an edit to your question as its a bit unclear to me what you're asking

Comment: @NaggappanRamukannan, dont forget to remove ``self``

Comment: The documentation for this solution is here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html